# Dynamic T-SQL input to T-SQL Task in SSIS

Tags: t-sql, ssis

My SSIS package includes a T-SQL task. I have a package parameter that I want to pass into my T-SQL task but I can't find the correct syntax to do this:

```
DECLARE @myVariable int;
SET @myVariable = $Package::myParameter --not working
SET @myVariable = @[$Package::myParameter] -- also not working
```

What is the correct way to pass parameters to a T-SQL task?

Comment: You want to pass a parameter into an execute sql task? What happens when you google _execute sql task parameter_

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Why would I google something about an sql task when when my problem involves a t-sql task?

Comment: Any reason you want to use  T-SQL instead of SQL? Because SQL can be parameterised. T-SQL Needs to have a string built beforehand. If you must use the T-SQL task, you need to learn about expressions

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I thought that T-SQL could only be run through a T-SQL Task but I was able to run it with a simple SQL task (so what is the purpose if this T-SQL task?). Anyway I'm curious about these "expressions" you mentioned.

Comment: I can never remember. I just google it. I never use a T-SQL task, only SQL. https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/11/ssis-execute-sql-task-vs-execute-t-sql-statement-task/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using an Execute SQL Task as it provides more functionality than an Execute T-SQL Statement Task.  However if you're looking to use the T-SQL Task with a parameter this can be done by creating a string variable with an expression that includes the parameter.  An example of this is below.  To set this as the statement for the T-SQL task, go to the Properties window of the task (press `F4`), click the ellipsis next to the `Expressions` field, select the `SqlStatementSource` property and add the string variable containing the T-SQL as the `Expression`.  Since the variable in your SQL is of the INT data type, I'm assuming the package parameter also is, thus it needs to be cast to a string to be included as part of the expression in the string variable.  This will still be parsed as a numeric data type and submitted to SQL Server as such.  This casting is done with the `(DT_STR, length, code page)` function below.  This just uses an example length of 10.  As a side note, the `(DT_WSTR, length)` function would be used for Unicode data.  Make sure to enclose the SQL text in quotes as done below.  Also be aware that parameter names are case sensitive within an expression, for example `@[$Package::MyParameter]` would return an error if the parameter name was `@[$Package::myParameter]`, starting with a lower case m.

```
"DECLARE @myVariable INT;
SET @myVariable = " + (DT_STR, 10, 1252)@[$Package::myParameter] + " 
UPDATE Database.Schema.Table
SET NAME = 'TW'
WHERE ID = @myVariable"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass parameters to a T-SQL task.

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-t-sql-statement-task?view=sql-server-2017):

> If you need to run parameterized queries, save the query results to
>   variables, or use property expressions, you should use the Execute SQL
>   task instead of the Execute T-SQL Statement task. For more
>   information, see Execute SQL Task.